# Error: Failed with exit code: 1 when try to "npm run make"

Tags: electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

I am currently trying to create the executable via this command "npm run make" except that it shows me the error :
`

```
✖ Making for target: squirrel - On platform: win32 - For arch: x64

An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
An error occured while making for target: squirrel
Failed with exit code: 1
Output:
Tentative de cr�ation du package depuis 'dashboard.nuspec'.
Description is required.

Error: Failed with exit code: 1
Output:
Tentative de cr�ation du package depuis 'dashboard.nuspec'.
Description is required.

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron-winstaller\lib\spawn-promise.js:49:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
```

`

I would like to know how to solve this error ?

Regards

Answer (score 5):

add author and description field in package.json as follows:

```
"author":"something but not empty",
"description":"something but not empty"
```

note that empty string that package.json by default has, is the reason for this error.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need a `"description"` field in your package.json. Also note that `npm run make` creates a Squirrel installer for your app exe. If you just want to package as a runnable exe not bundled into an installer, do `npm run package`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When i do `npm run package`, it works. But i have a `"description"` field in the package.json, do i have to fill this field for the `npm run make` to work ?

Comment: Yes, you have to have a `description` and it can't be an empty string, the Squirrel make will fail if that field is empty or missing.